# SQL miss transfer some data to another table under transaction

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have query which transfer data from one database to another.
Query is controlled by Maintenance plan and it's executed each 10 sec.
SQL server isolation level is read committed.
Over query we are transfer over 500 000 records and last month we have 8 missing records.
Any idea what can cause this incorrect behavior for only couple records.
Also sp for log errors did not catch anything.

```
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @BatchSize Int = 2000;
DECLARE @Rows                       Int = 1,
        @MaxTransferedTransactionID Int,
        @MaxTransactionID           Int;

WHILE @Rows > 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SET @MaxTransferedTransactionID = 0
            SET @MaxTransactionID = 0

            --Get max transfered ID
            SELECT @MaxTransferedTransactionID = Max(tTransferTransactionLog.TransactionID)
            FROM   dbo.tTransferTransactionLog

            SET @MaxTransferedTransactionID = Coalesce(@MaxTransferedTransactionID, 0)

            --Get ID of last inserted transaction, with max batch site 2000
            SELECT @MaxTransactionID = Max(ID)
            FROM   dbo.tTransaction
            WHERE  ID > @MaxTransferedTransactionID AND
                   ID <= (@MaxTransferedTransactionID + @BatchSize)

            IF (IsNull(@MaxTransactionID, 0) = 0)
                BREAK;

            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            --insert first table 
            INSERT INTO dbo.tNak (IDNaknada)
                        SELECT tNakn.IDNaknada
                        FROM   tNakn
                        WHERE  tNakn.ID > @MaxTransferedTransactionID AND
                               tNakn.ID <= @MaxTransactionID

            --insert second table 
            INSERT INTO dbo.tTransaction (IDTransakcije,
                                          DatumTransakcije,
                                          IznosTransakcije)
                        SELECT tTransaction.IDTransakcije,
                               tTransaction.DatumTransakcije,
                               tTransaction.IznosTransakcije
                        FROM   dbo.tTransaction
                        WHERE  tTransakcije.ID > @MaxTransferedTransactionID AND
                               tTransakcije.ID <= @MaxTransactionID

            SET @Rows = @@RowCount;

            INSERT INTO dbo.tTransferTransactionLog (TransactionID,
                                                     TransferDate,
                                                     RowsCount)
            VALUES (@MaxTransactionID, -- TransactionID
                    GetDate(),         -- TransferDate
                    @Rows)

            IF @@TranCount > 0
                COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF Xact_State() <> 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            EXEC dbo.error_handler_sp
            SET @Rows = 0
        END CATCH
    END
```

Comment: Which table had missing records? Is the ID column in both tables an IDENTITY column?

Comment: Also, have you considered using Replication on these tables instead of the job running every 10 seconds?

Comment: 1. You have some checks that execute outside the transaction 2. You are probably under `READ COMMITTED` so it's possible for some joined parent rows to be excluded, while still being missed on the next run. `SERIALIZABLE` would solve this, at the cost of some concurrency. 3. It's unclear why you have all that logic anyway. Why not just do a standard `TOP`, outputting IDs into a table variable, then just take the maximum ID and go again (Keyset Pagination style) 4. Agreed you should consider replication etc.

Comment: Thk. all.
We are find reason for this problem in this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285413/missing-rows-under-read-committed-isolation